# If user is in table show else do not PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page on my site that if the column 'active' in my table is not null then show my user, if not dont bother.

Before I go further though, say I have 100 users, having this query on my page will that slow speed down a lot? Basically I have my query on my index page, so when users visit I want it to run, and pull all of my data from my table...

```
while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
    echo '<div class="user">'.$r["user"].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Performance is relative.  I wouldn't worry about it until 1) speed is the most pressing problem your app has 2) this is identified as a bottleneck.

Comment: 100 users is nothing; performance will decrease noticeably - by seconds - somewhere between 10,000-100,000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. You should not see a significant delay for a reasonable amount of users. However, if you are anticipating thousands of users, you might be better off using any number of practices to optimize performance, like:

- Paging: Using a `LIMIT` clause with your queries and an assortment of links to provide access to all user records. This way, no matter how much your table may grow, performance will stay constantly high.
- A simple text search form for the user name. Consider having to browse through a couple hundred users just to reach a particular one, versus having the server do that for you. If you go that way, don't forget to index the fields the search would apply to to ensure optimal performance.
- Index the fields you 're using as criteria in your query, which is covered by ndefontenay and I 'm just mentioning it for completeness.

---

EDIT: Regarding your question, if what you want is to get all users where the field `active` is not null, you can do it like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM User WHERE active IS NOT NULL
```

A small note: In terms of performance, it is best to specify the fields you want to retrieve instead of collecting all fields. If, for example, you wanted to retrieve the user name and email for each user, you could do it like:

```
 SELECT username, email FROM User WHERE active IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @Ioannis Karadimas, regarding the if field is Null how do I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks more like a SQL question rather than a PHP question.

Your query looks like this:

select username, fullname, whatever_else from usertable where active = 1;

This should be a really fast query if you create an index on your active column:

```
create index idx_active 
on usertable
(active desc);
```

I made the index descending so that the value 1 is lined up first (in my example 1 is active 0 inactive and the active column is an integer).

I assume that on the long run, you will have a lot less active people than inactive people as well. You will always query a small substract of your table usertable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also @KSimson is right but I would get it right in the first place. It's just good practice.

Comment: Thanks @ndefontenay, regarding the if field is Null how do I go about that? – Liam just now edit

Comment: If your query returns 0 results, you can just use if (count($r) > 0) { echo '<div class="user">'.$r["user"].'</div>';
}

Comment: Try to get your performance right with best practices from the start that is if you know something can work faster, make it so. If you adopt a sloppiness, when your site grows, you will find out that it's not one bottleneck but pretty much everything which requires improvement and it's a lot harder then! (Build with success and thousands of users in mind)